# How can I create a Mac application that display content on desktop/background?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am considering making an app to simply display some info (say time) on desktop, in a way like it were a part of wallpaper:

1. This app only displays time (like "12:34") on Desktop - only numbers, no regular window stuff like background, border, or menu;
2. These numbers don't interact with user - like wallpaper;
3. These numbers stay behind all other apps and icons - like wallpaper too;
4. This app doesn't appear in Dock or "Force Quit..." list;

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Like hauntsaninja said, NSWindowLevel should help a lot.

Also, to hide the dock icon, go to your application's Info.plist and add "Application is agent (UIElement)" and tick it.

Comment: I have tested it. You are right, "Application is agent (UIElement)" does the job. Thx

Comment: Great! :) I'm glad it worked! Just saying, but if it completely works and you're happy then you could mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: The view u created will hide when user tap 'FN+F11' to display the desktop

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to avoid it from appearing on your Dock or your Force Quit list, but here's how you'd do the window thing: add a `[window setLevel:kCGDesktopWindowLevel]` call to your code.

Here are two lists of what all you can set it to:
The 'Window Levels' section of  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html
and some more at:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSWindowLevel